# cassandra key cache hit rate differs between nodetool and opscenter

Tags: caching, cassandra, opscenter, nodetool

I checked my key cache hit rate via nodetool and opscenter, the first shows a hit rate of 0.907 percent.

Key Cache              : entries 1152104, size 96.73 MB, capacity 100 MB, 52543777 hits, 57954469 requests, 0.907 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds

but in opscenter the graph shows 100%.
[image]

any one understands why the difference?

Comment: what version of C* and opscenter are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra has a perhaps bug (or at least typo) here, it lists it as recent hit cache but its of all time:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/nodetool/Info.java#L95

Its grabbing the value of the "total" hitrate:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/metrics/CacheMetrics.java#L66

So although you may be getting 100% hit rate for the last 19 minutes according to opscenter it wasn't always 100%. The total number of hits / total number of requests of all time is ~90%.

This is shown from:

```
52543777 hits, 57954469 requests

52543777 / 57954469 = 0.907
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that the `HitRate` reported in Codahale metrics is still lifetime. So people may want to use `OneMinuteHitRate` (or friends) instead. [Here's the code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/50027f52322b7c0006c0b3c51cc6517c252e7e59/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/metrics/CacheMetrics.java#L75-L86).